# Add VueJS to preset snippet options

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets

### Request

As the title says, I would like [`vue`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN) added to the preset libraries already present under the options portion:

[image: location, location, location]

The following are links that can be used for this:

> [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@[VERSION_NUMBER]/dist/vue.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@%5BVERSION_NUMBER%5D/dist/vue.js)

Example, the latest version being https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js

### Reasoning

I often find myself answering Vue questions, but having to go and find the link to put into the external library dialogue. It makes answer questions that much more difficult, especially considering I want to be able to just select and go.

Vue is a major player in the front-end space now, and I believe it would be good to consider this. We have React and Angular, so why not Vue?

*Thank you for your time and consideration!*

Comment: [Ah, Vue, j'avais pas Vue!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFfZhRfgLrE)

Comment: Alternative - a single menu where you can select multiple libraries, or add your own.

Comment: Note that's AngularJS they have on there, not Angular (which, as of this comment, is on version 7). jQuery doesn't have versions past 2.1.1 (and they're on 3.1.1). I think they should use something like [cdnjs.com's API](https://cdnjs.com/api) to pull the appropriate version lists for each library they wish to support.

Comment: Your input might be helpful here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392751/vue-js-cdn-in-development-mode

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of November 26th, 2018, vue.js is a selectable library in the snippet editor. All recent release versions available on cdnjs should be selectable; please let me know if you encounter any issues.