# How to better focus my time as an answerer?

Tags: discussion

On multiple occasions, I have begun to compose an answer to a question, and have put a great deal of time and effort into constructing diagrams, and making graphs, only to discover that, by the time I am actually ready to submit my answer, the question has been closed by a moderator.

My usual process is to first convince myself that there is a clear thing that the OP wants, then to research the problem, in case there already exists a solution on Stack Overflow, and then, in case I do not find one, to begin working on a solution and a relevant explanation.  However, my ideas of what constitutes a clear question, or what questions are sufficiently covered by answers to other questions are not universal, and sometimes a moderator has a different conclusion about whether or not a question is clear and/or solved.

Most recently, I have spent at least 2 hours constructing an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200783/how-to-convert-image-from-rgb-to-greyscale?noredirect=1#comment100915815_57200783).  The question seemed clear enough to me, and seemed to ask a sufficiently different thing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835753/convert-grayscale-value-to-rgb-representation) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python).  Since there is not some objective "duplicateness" metric out there, I can only judge for myself.  Having spent 2 hours composing an answer, I have returned to discover that it has been closed.  [Asking that it be reopened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387688/request-to-un-duplicate-question?noredirect=1#comment715624_387688) got a response that I, essentially, do not have [standing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_(law)).

This particular example is mostly irrelevant.  The point is that this has happened to me more than once, and I have spent a great deal of time answering open questions, only to discover that in the meantime they have been closed.  This is incredibly frustrating, and causes me to feel as though my time spent answering questions on SO is wasted.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I better focus my time?  Does anybody else experience this?

Comment: I sympathise with the problem. However, I guess we need to be careful to ensure that "on-topic" does not come to mean "I spent lots of time composing an answer". Sadly, some things just are off-topic.

Comment: Where this has happened to me in the past, I put what I can on a Gist, and add a link in the comments, so the effort is not wasted. Of course, you can separately lobby for a question to be reopened too - perhaps by going to the relevant chat room.

Comment: @halfer "we need to be careful to ensure that "on-topic" does not come to mean "I spent lots of time composing an answer"" I agree with this statement.  "Sadly, some things just are off-topic" I disagree with this statement.  The definition of on-topic is vague enough to allow a lot of discretion to the individual doing the closing, and I think intentionally so.  This is good, because it prevents a lot of "paperwork" when closing a question, but creates a situation where what is off-topic is not always crystal clear.

Comment: I think that this trade-off was made consciously.  My question is mostly that, given the non-crystal-clarity of off-topicness/duplicateness/other-closable-offensiveness, what can I do to avoid spending time answering such questions?

Comment: The question you included the link to is not closed now FWIW.

Comment: Linked question sure seems overly broad with zero effort shown to make an attempt at a solution or reflect any research effort. Even if it's not a duplicate ; being too broad sure seems like valid off topic reason. That said,  have had same thing happen numerous times over the years

Comment: One thing you can do is compose your answers offline, or in another tab, (or in a Gist as mentioned by @halfer), and refresh the question periodically to view its current state. You could theoretically waste less time that way.

Comment: @Scott "The definition of on-topic is vague enough to allow a lot of discretion to the individual doing the closing, and I think intentionally so" err... no. There are a lot of things that are very explicitly off-topic, such as polls, questions asking for opinions, shopping list questions, questions asking why a something was implemented the way it was, questions asking for off-site resources, etc. There are yet more questions that may be on-topic _if they include the requisite information necessary to answer the question_.

Comment: The subjectivity only really exists in the "Too Broad" and "Unclear what you're asking" close reasons.

Comment: Probably you need to spend more time thinking about whether the question belongs on our site and whether it meets our quality definitions *before* answering. If it's questionable, wait until it becomes clear. If experienced users are commenting and pointing out flaws with the question, then follow their lead and wait until attempting to answer. Just because someone asks a question doesn't mean we must answer it.

Comment: Depending on why you answering the question, the situation isn’t so dire. As you have spent 2 hours, i assume you don’t do it (only) for rep - your goal to learn something is already achieved. It sucks that the work isn’t documented - you could add your answer to a duplicate target or create and self-answer a Q&A, if this is different enough and on-topic.

Comment: @ead "your goal to learn something is already achieved" this is true.  :)  However, I am a teacher at heart, and was a university instructor for years.  As such, my motives are mostly not selfish in nature, and so when I set out to answer questions, it is not for rep and not for my personal benefit, it is to benefit those who are asking questions.

Comment: @ead, this might illustrate my problem, though.  I think that I may be subconsciously drawn to questions where the asker seems *extra confused*.  It is unfortunately difficult to ask a well-reasoned and explicit question unless you are 80% unconfused.  I'll try to watch out for this in the future.

Comment: I have to ask - you write elaborate answers which take several hours to complete. You are as you say drawn to questions where the asker seems extra confused. One seems to follow from the other in my eyes. Are you not forced to write answers which require a great deal of effort because you have to cover too many bases? Wouldn't it be better to try and take away some of the confusion first through comments so you can write a more to the point answer? Because that will at the same time help to stop questions from being closed...

Comment: "Wouldn't it be better to try and take away some of the confusion first through comments."  Not necessarily, because [as discussed on meta in numerous places](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130975/are-comments-ephemeral-and-what-should-be-done-with-informative-comments) comments are ephemeral, and so others with a similar confusion may not benefit from them....

Comment: ... In the question [linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200783/how-to-convert-image-from-rgb-to-greyscale?noredirect=1#comment100915815_57200783), the asker wants to know how to invert an RGB to grayscale mapping.  The question is "incorrect" in a sense, in that it has no answer, because such a mapping in not invertible.  However, this doesn't mean that others might not have the same question.

Comment: [The help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) specifically requires that "You should only ask practical, answerable questions."  The "correct" question *might* be "Why can't we invert an RGB to grayscale mapping?"  But this implies that the asker knows that such a mapping cannot be inverted.  This 1) isn't the question that occurs to people, though and 2) isn't, ostensibly, a programming question at all!, even though "How do I invert an RGB to grayscale mapping?" *is*.

Comment: ... but I digress.  Your suggestion is solid, and I will take it under consideration.  :)

Comment: It will help a bit when you get to 3K rep (I think that's the number), so you can see if there are already some close votes on the question.

Comment: @DontPanic (sigh).  I'm so very tired of fighting to gain rep.  I've been an active member for *over 5 years*.  If stackoverflow doesn't want me to have certain privileges at this point I'm simply resigned to go without them.