# Where are Stack Overflow Enterprise release notes posted?

Tags: support, product-support, stack-overflow-enterprise

I have searched

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com,
- https://stackoverflow.com,
- https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise,
- https://stackoverflow.blog
- https://twitter.com/stackoverflow
- Google

and have been unable to locate release notes. My employer uses Stack Overflow Enterprise but when new releases are installed its not clear what has been fixed, changed, added, etc. to the site or the API.

Also, when we are behind, and there is a known issue, I would like to be able to look ahead and see that it has been addressed in a future release.

---

Related posts that provide some insight:

- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) (thanks @rene)

Comment: What is public available is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange but that is maintained by the community and based on observation. If you have an Enterprise licence I would contact SE support.

Comment: I appreciate that link. I don't think the Enterprise product and the public site have the same features or release schedule, but that's another question.

Comment: That is correct. On the public site there are daily releases. I've pinged someone in chat and I'm told your question will get a response from SE staff.

Comment: I have not seen a response from SE staff.

Comment: Better use the [Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) page. SE Staff probably didn't get a ticket assigned from my informal ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be another public source available, but I have since discovered the release notes are published on the Stack Overflow Enterprise Solutions Portal which is available to SOE customers.

On the main page of the portal there is a main section called Release Notes:

[image]