# Are questions about how comments are moderated off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta, moderation

About an hour ago, the question [When are comments deleted on Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388097/7296893) got locked with a collaborative lock, marked as a FAQ, and all answers but the lowest score one got deleted. Around the same time, a comment was added stating the following:

> mod note - the mod team has decided how they will moderate comments, hence there is only one correct answer to the question - the only specifying how the actual moderator team is moderating. It's not open to community debate, it's dictated by the site owner's code of conduct and standards.

However, the discussion has not been about comments that were against the code of conduct. It has always been clear how those were moderated. It's unclear to me which *site owner's standards* that comment is referring to.

A future question discussing comment moderation has also been marked as a duplicate of this locked FAQ post.

Since the post has a collaborative lock and the moderators apparently prohibit and close further discussion, how should we proceed? Should we just accept it as a fact that moderators have a unilateral say in moderation policy, and are allowed to shut down further discussion about it for unclear reasons?

---

<sub>To the moderator team: I'm sorry. I get that you have been putting in extreme amounts of work recently, and have the good of the site at heart. I have to ask this because it's an unprecedented development that clearly limits the say of the meta community. I get that people are tired, and would not blame any of you for not participating in this discussion around comment moderation, or any future ones. Accepting that future discussion on the subject is disallowed is one step too far for me.</sub>

Comment: I think why that thread was closed because it was not about suggestion and correction as to how mods moderate comments. It was about **How are comments moderated** and people were disagreeing and stating their opinion as to how the comments should be moderated

Comment: When will we finally accept that the only people in this entire equation who can *actually* moderate comments are diamond moderators? Squabbling about how you think they should go about it, in all frankness, is a waste of time.

Comment: @Makoto When someone finally makes it explicit that this is how things work. Questions like this keep being asked because nobody ever answers them

Comment: I'm really not sure what's left to be answered. So long as your comments are topical, respectful, and relate to the matter at hand, they stand a *very* low chance of being removed. "Don't be a jerk" as guiding principle seems like it'd be enough. Were you interested in exact circumstances and examples of unacceptable comments?

Comment: @Makoto This isn't about that. I haven't been involved in that discussion much. It's about the question if the moderators should decide that some topics are just off limits for MSO even if they're on-topic, and that's something that _is_ relevant to me.

Comment: Yeah, that reads like "exact circumstances" to me. You're describing a paradox in which something which is off-limits can also be on-topic. Some conversations may be uncomfortable, but so long as they're not off-topic or devolving into a free Two Minutes Hate, I can't see the moderators overstepping their boundaries.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to more accurately reflect your stated intent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Discussion about comment moderation on Meta is not being shut down, as shown by the numerous questions on the matter over the last two weeks (including one posted by yours truly). The specific question being discussed here is a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) meant to document how the moderators are currently handling comments, and not a discussion intended to set or tweak the current practices. That being so, it makes sense to lock it, and to remove answers that do not aim at documenting current practice.

On the topicality of comment moderation discussions, it is worth quoting [a comment by George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388391/are-questions-about-how-comments-are-moderated-off-topic-here/388394?noredirect=1#comment720929_388394):

> I have no issues with discussing it: it’s the same as it always was: duplicate conversations are closed; new conversations or questions on specific actions aren’t generally duplicates.

Comment: I would hold that to be true, if not for the fact that other discussions got marked as a duplicate of the faq post.

Comment: @ErikA Do you mean [*How does the moderation team intend to move forward on Meta comment moderation?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388179/2751851)

Comment: @duplode there's also this, closed as duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388388/why-is-george-stocker-deleting-his-own-comments-and-high-value-comments-by-other

Comment: I meant both of those. That, including _It's not open to community debate_ in that comment lead me to conclude we're no longer allowed to discuss how comments should be moderated on meta.

Comment: It can always be discussed; I just don’t know how many different ways we can say “comments will be moderated in line with existing standards for all SE sites”. Meta.so was singularly special in how it was moderated. It is now being brought closer to all other SE sites.

Comment: @George The point is: it's not in line with other meta SE sites at all. Not global meta, not meta.SU, not any meta I followed discussions on. Meta and main are different. While I get that it's easier to have one guideline regardless of where comments are posted, I think that's not helpful for at least one of the two sites.

Comment: @ErikA The "How does the moderation team [...]" one is straightforwardly a duplicate (A: "By moderating them as documented in the \[faq\] question"). As for the other one, presumably the answer is that George is applying those same moderation guidelines in a way he deems appropriate, and that the mod team finds that a reasonable approach (not that the personalised take of that question was all that helpful to begin with). On "not open to community debate", I'd be wary of reading too much into that single turn of phrase.

Comment: The timing seemed to insinuate differently. But I guess I have George's word that it can always be discussed and you're right.

Comment: I have no issues with discussing it: it’s the same as it always was: duplicate conversations are closed; new conversations or questions on specific actions aren’t generally duplicates.