# Vue.js CDN in development mode

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

The insert "Stack Snippets" feature on Stack Overflow's WYSIWYG editor has the option to add [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js). When you add the library, it pulls in the un-minified development version of Vue.js. This version includes a few `console.info()` messages. These messages are visible when clicking "Run code snippet", demo below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

**Is there a reason Stack Overflow chose to use the development version of Vue.js?** In most cases, I find myself manually switching out the script for the minified version to suppress these messages.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
```

**How would I go about requesting this feature be changed?**

Comment: I'm not a vue.js user.  Does the development version output extra diagnostic information while running that could be helpful in some cases, or is it just intended to be more user friendly if a developer needs to debug into it?

Comment: @DanNeely yes, that is absolutely correct. The extra information is very useful when developing. However, on SO, it just seems to clutter up the console outputs.

Comment: Can some of the extra information be helpful at the snippet scale, or does it only really come into its own at scales too big for an SO question?

Comment: I would say that is up for debate. I would like to see how other Vue.js users feel about it.

Comment: Not a hard core Vue dev here, but I'm with Marc on this one. The development version is clouding the console with unnecessary info (and occasionally "advertising" the Vue devtools browser extension - [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671714/set-one-of-two-classes-according-to-a-boolean-variable)).

Comment: Another thing to note: React has similar messages. Stack Overflow uses the minified production distribution that doesn't contain these warnings. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js. VS https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js

Answer (score 4):

Vue is in the list due to this request: [Add VueJS to preset snippet options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376307/add-vuejs-to-preset-snippet-options)

As that request used the non-minified option, I complied. I have no particular opinion on this personally, but let's see what other Vue.js aficionados here on SO have to say.